# how to run a standalone Capybara test?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm trying to run a test against a remote server. i.e:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'


module MyCapybaraTest
  include Capybara

  def test_google
    visit('/')
  end
end
```

question is, how do you run it?

Answer (score 21):

Save

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'

module MyCapybaraTest
  class Test
    include Capybara::DSL
    def test_google
      visit('/')
    end
  end
end

t = MyCapybaraTest::Test.new
t.test_google
```

to `test.rb` and simply: `ruby test.rb`

Comment: Good answer. This works as-is for me with capybara (0.4.1.2)
and capybara-webkit (0.5.0) under Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Also, to run this sort of test headless, use the `capybara-mechanize` gem. Add `require 'capybara/mechanize'` and `Capybara.current_driver = :mechanize` to the code.

Comment: Also works with newest versions: capybara-1.1.2 and capybara-webkit 0.11.0

Comment: How should we use "describe"/"it" block with this strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I found this standalone cucumber thingy using the selenium driver a few days ago and got it up and running in a few minutes:

https://github.com/thuss/standalone-cucumber

I had to make a few mods:

My Gemfile is

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

group(:test) do
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.5.0'
end
```

And this is my env.rb

```
begin require 'rspec/expectations'; rescue LoadError; require 'spec/expectations'; end
require 'capybara' 
require 'capybara/dsl' 
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://something'
World(Capybara)
```